# Display UTC date/time into date/time according to the current timezone

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am getting a date/time string from web in the format of "yyyy/mm/dd'T'HH:MM:SS'Z'" and it is in UTC.

Now I have to identify the current time zone of device and then convert this time to my local time..

How do I do it?

(FYI, Currently, UTC time is 10:25 AM, in India current time is 3:55 PM)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `TimeZone.getDefault()` instead of `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")`

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> ... you get a TimeZone using
>   getDefault  which creates a TimeZone
>   based on the time zone where the
>   program is running.

EDIT: You can parse date using [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (there is also the documentation on the format string there). In your case, you want to do (untested):

```
 // note that I modified the format string slightly
 SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
 // set the timezone to the original date string's timezone
 fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
 Date date = fmt.parse("1998/12/21T13:29:31Z", new ParsePosition(0));

 // then reset to the target date string's (local) timezone
 fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
 String localTime = fmt.format(date);
```

alternatively, use two separate instances of SimpleDateFormat, one for original and one for target time.

Comment: @Lei Ryan but dear i know how to do parsing and formatting the date, but want to display UTC into Local timezone

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: you should say so in your question. See my updated answer

Comment: @Lei Ryan This is working!! Found your past answer very helpful, from that i done the same code as you have done. Btw, thanx for the quick response and support

Comment: Are you sure that's the format you've got? mm is minutes, MM is months. It would look very odd to have minutes in between years and days